# High wattage 12 to 5 V

Tags: dc-dc-converter, high-power

I have an LED project with a pretty hefty power draw - 1.5 kilowatts. We're trying to figure out how to power this from a (large) 12 V battery bank.

We need to have the entire 1.5 kW output travel down a single pair of wires (slip ring).

Are there 12 V to 5 V DC converters that can do this?

I was originally thinking I could just wire together a bunch of smaller buck converters (such as [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CEP3A0Q)) but I'm learning that you need converters that can do "current sharing", and it's not clear to me how to identify 12 - 5 V converters that can do that.

Comment: You need 300 A at 5 V? Through a "single pair of wires"? You'd better plan on those wires being pretty hefty (on the order of 175 \$\rm mm^2\$). Whether you can get 300 A through a reasonable slip ring is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Maybe boost to 100 or 200 V to go through the slip ring, then buck down to 5 V on the rotating side?

Comment: How fast will the slip ring be rotating? what if the slip ring contact has occasionally "opens"?

Comment: Does it have to be a 12V battery bank? Could you connect batteries in series? If you can't then it's worth converting 12V --> 100V, that reduces the current to 15A which you could easily get in a carbon slipring. Then go 100VDC to whatever final supply you need. I can't imagine 5V is a good target voltage, perhaps put some of the LEDs (arrays I assume) in series and feed with a constant current supply.

Comment: There are a heap of cheap 4-5A sliprings available such as this: https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-6Wires-220V-380V-5A-12-7MM-Dia-Metal-Capsule-Conductors-Slip-Ring/183878035191?  This would give you 30A capability if needed.

Comment: But he needs **125A** at 12V

Comment: "Are there 12v to 5v DC converters that can do this?" - why 5V?

Comment: Is this an LED array? If so, can they be wired in series and driven by a much higher voltage? Or... is it possible to have local down-conversion on the moving part from a higher voltage applied to the slip-rings? These would be easier than 300A slip rings I think.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing about the high amps, but my buddy convinced me that we're not sending more wattage through it than comes out of a wall socket, we'd be fine, but I was pretty skeptical.

Comment: I don't think we can do that kind of voltage transformation. Aside from the expense of the parts, this is an otherwise janky art object. That also means the slip ring shouldn't be turning much, only when people push on it, and it's not exactly conducive (as an object) to being spun fast.

Comment: It's 5v because it's an array of 4400 WS 2813 LEDs (plus two arduinos and a pi), and that's the native voltage for those.

Comment: @Narfanator Your buddy is wrong, losses in wires are proportional to square of current and not wattage.

Comment: It seems you do not have a feasible power distribution plan as this requires hefty cable that costs more than your LEDs.  It may be better to distribute AC per to DC supplies every 5m

Comment: I have never seen a high current slip ring like you are looking for... Typically the voltage is boosted for that power level. Consider using a semi standard 48v.

Comment: Interesting! I was tasked with something very similar a couple of years ago, although two orders of magnitude less power. I suggested the same “high voltage” approach several here suggested and mount the buck inductor close to the axis to minimize unbalance and force strain on the solder joints.

Comment: @Narfanator _"... my buddy convinced me that we're not sending more wattage through it than comes out of a wall socket, we'd be fine ..."_ - A welding machine is also not sending more wattage through its business end than comes out of the wall socket. But I'm guessing you know what the welder can do to metal...

Comment: @marcelm good point! In the end we put 120V AC through the slip ring, and do the power conversion on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that you need 5V for the strips, you could segment them and supply them locally with individual 5V. So maybe five groups powered by a 60A 5V supply each. Then use an inverter to make 120V from your 12V battery bank to power the slip rings.

Check this out: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07G7S44CW/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G7S44CW)

And this: [https://www.amazon.com/Power-TechOn-Inverter-Outlets-PS1002/dp/B0131L8NLM/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0131L8NLM)

Just make sure you idiot-proof the slip rings. Maybe use a GFCI on them after the inverter.

And here’s a 10A slip ring: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13063

And a 30A (!) one: [https://www.amazon.com/Wires-Generator-250Rpm-Power-Collector/dp/B00MYYTWQ8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MYYTWQ8)

Answer (score 0):

Look for DC to DC converters that have a clock sync and/or parallelizable:

Here is a list from analog of [high current DC to DC converters](https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11491#/p5344=%7CYes&p5347=min%7C5&p5349=50%7C200&p5357=5%7Cmax&p5362=Buck&p5573=min%7C6&p5574=12%7Cmax&d=sel%7C5368%7C5345%7C5344%7C5362%7Cs3%7Cs5%7C5351%7C5349%7C5347%7C5357%7C5573%7C5574%7C5575). None of them got to the 300A you require, but some go to from 60A to 90A, in which you could parallel three or four of them. However DC to DC converters can be difficult to size components correctly and required a lot of time reading in the datasheet and a certain amount of skill which is not for everyone (especially me, when I got the wrong mosfets and the converter doesn't work on it's first cut).

[image]
Source: https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc3884.html

There are also high current LED drivers like the [LT3761](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt3761a.html) which can handle 100A:

[image]

It may be better to follow Jack Creasey's comment and buy off the shelf ones. Sometimes they can be difficult to parallel if the voltage outputs are not matched well.

It would also be better to send the 12V (or higher) across the slip ring to reduce losses from the contacts and have the 5V conversion after the slip ring to reduce I^2*R losses from the slip ring contacts.

Comment: If each one powers its own set of leds then matching the output voltage may not be an issue.

Comment: @SolarMike agree, and have suggested exactly that knowing that they're using addressable LED strips. Divide and conquer.